# How to remove "/" from Date and append with url?

Tags: android, date, android-volley

MyActivity

```
myurl  private static final String url ="https://tripfareapi.herokuapp.com/flightapi/src=DEL&dest=BOM&depdate=";
```

Getting values using `Intent`

```
      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String from = bundle.getString("from");
        String to = bundle.getString("to");
       depaturedate = bundle.getString("departuredate");
```

*my url where i want the append original url with selected date which i am geeting from intent*

```
newurl = url+depaturedate;
```

**My volley**

```
  private void getdata() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(newurl,new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    requestQueue.add(request);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask,do you want to remove '/' from a string ??

Comment: i have date in this format 2018/04/24 and i want in 20180424 and append with url

Comment: You can use .replace function,something like this datestring.replace("/","")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String depDate= formatter.format(depaturedate);
url += depDate;
```

To use `SimpleDateFormat` you have to `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

For `String`:

```
departuredate = departuredate.replace("/", "");
url += departuredate;
```

Comment: did not work for me showing this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: is departureDate a variable of type `Date` or is it a `String`?

Comment: It is of String Type

Comment: any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Edited answer for string

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
depaturedate = depaturedate.replace("/", "");
newurl = url+depaturedate;
```

Comment: add a log statement after calling `replace` method and check the value of `depaturedate`